# Assigning name attributes to objects in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

We create test automation for a WPF application based on the objects and the names of the objects. We don't have access to the WPF source code. Not all name attributes are filled, which makes test automation difficult.

Is there a way to assign name attributes to objects from the outside, without having access to the source code in any way? I know this is almost certain impossible to do, but I want to make sure I don't overlook a solution here, as it would make our test automation effort so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any way to change the name attributes.
But maybe you can use some other means of identifying the objects.
We use for our UI Tests the [TestStack.White](https://teststackwhite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) Framework, which allows to get an object based on different criterias, like the ID, the name, by type, class name etc. Maybe this could help you circumvent your problem.
In order to figure out these attributes we use the [UIAVerify Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library) and [Inspect.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx) from Microsoft.

Comment: Yes, exactly. 
In our team we have a colleague who creates automation tests for WPF application, and from time to time I have to support him, as there are sometimes UI elements, that are not accessible for him.
There are frameworks that automatically generates names for every attribute, but they mess the code, and won't help you in some corner cases (3rd party controls).